# Build an Indy-SDK web demo

Tags: hyperledger-indy

I am trying to build a simple Indy-SDK Agent in python with a Web interface on a Ubuntu VPS Server.
https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/tree/master/samples
I was looking at those samples. Much testing there.
Is there some other source you guys use to build a simple indy demo with some simple DID actions and a wallet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the samples are more or less only for understanding the indy flow and all the stuff around indy.

There are basically 2 things:

1. Ledger
2. your application aka indy application

**1) Ledger**

First thing, you will need to create your private ledger. The best way is to use they [script which runs docker containers](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/57ece1dd5c28f0fb0196591c51697b9de274fced/samples/nodejs/package.json#L10) as peer network with indy servers. Once the servers are up you should be ready to connect your application to indy network.

**2) Application**

Your application needs to know [genesis](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/57ece1dd5c28f0fb0196591c51697b9de274fced/samples/python/src/utils.py#L25) tx to be able to connect to the ledger. Once your application is connected you can develop your logic. The [getting started code](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/src/getting_started.py) should be enough. It covers 2) in the list below and it also creates DIDs for all entities with steward role.

So before doing your specific implementation you should understand and be familiar with:

1. [Indy documentation](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/tree/master/docs)
2. [Indy getting started](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/docs/getting-started/getting-started.svg) diagram - basic indy flow
3. Watch [this demonstration video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WZxlrGMA3s)

So, if you want to create Web Interfaces it should be basically copy&paste from getting-started sample.

Also if you just want to demonstrate what indy can do and you dont have time or resources to build your own application, you can take a look at [this demonstration](https://medium.com/@kctheservant/exploring-agent-demonstration-in-hyperledger-indy-3e1e8278b3d1). It's more complex application with Aries and User interfaces but you have web ui with all the stuff.